# Which Linux Kernel supports a Thunderbolt display port in a PC laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-compatibility

I recently got a PC laptop with a Thunderbolt display. I would like to install Linux but which Kernel version can support a Thunderbolt display?

Comment: The stock kernels in some distributions enable everything as a module. What is your distribution?

Comment: I reckon I will install Fedora 21 (Kernel 3.17)

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Comment: "Thunderbolt DisplayPort" makes no sense. It is one or another(Either Thunderbolt or DisplayPort). Maybe you coulde be talking about Mini DisplayPort - http://www.cnet.com/news/confusing-mini-displayport-with-thunderbolt/. Which one of them it is?

Comment: @nwildner Thunderbolt controllers multiplex one or more individual data lanes from connected PCIe and DisplayPort devices for transmission via two duplex Thunderbolt lanes, then de-multiplex them for use by PCIe and DisplayPort devices on the other end....

Comment: Yeah. The time i wrote that comment, i wasn't aware about Thunderbolt encapsulating information of other protocols, like it is done today with external GPUs, or external "mini-motherboards" that holds GPU, USB and DVI/HDMI ports. Its a comment of more that 2,5 years ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

PC laptop with a Thunderbolt display port? only?
So, you want to use your Thunderbolt port for external display ?

Well, you either need a monitor with a thunderbolt port, or a cable with thunderbolt port on one side and the desired port on the other side.

As for the Linux Kernel version, [version 3.17 adds support for thunderbolt](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.17#head-760fb2b63a9ddee7d23b164b03ec116dcfdf73e0), inlcuding as a display